# imageview is empty when I try to show an image from SD card

Tags: java, android

imageview is empty when I try to show an image from SD card. Can someone help me? When the image exists, the image view is set to blank. (I have a JPEG file `Pikachu.jpg`).

From Java class:

```
File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Pikachu.jpg");

        if(image.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
             Toast.makeText(this,"ok ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{      
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

XML file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: why don't you use myImage.setImageUri(...)?

Comment: If image is of very high quality and very big then it won't show. Give a try to set  `android:largeHeap="true"`  in application tag of your manifest file.

Comment: i tried using setimageUri, but it also give me a blank image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing the file constructor to the following

```
File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pikachu.jpg");
```

Comment: i tried but the imageview still blank when i try to change them

Comment: Are you sure about the path of the image? maybe it exists in a directory in the SD card

Comment: i made an if condition. and it makes me a toast "Ok"

Comment: @VictorBeraldo Did you add the permission read external storage<br>
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`